# Careers in Chess

Tags: careers

What are the different career options in Chess? The obvious and famous one is being a professional player, and the next best one is that of a chess coach. 
What are the other careers that involve chess?

Comment: Intesting question +1

Comment: Which of these is not like the others:

A. Physician B. Welder C. Chess professional D. Large pizza

(C) is different - the others can feed a family of 4.

Comment: Very true @TonyEnnis I was never able to make a decent living playing tournaments. I started working for chess startups, and also as a chess coach.

Comment: I know a great chess player in Paris... He does Professional Street Miming to help him not starve .. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My list of answers after much thinking..

Chess careers:

- Professional players
- Coaches
- Preparation and playing partners
- Arbiters
- Chess writers
- Chess photographers
- Chess officials for federations
- Chess programmers
- Chess commentators
- Chess journalist
- Managers - for players
- Columists
- Chess artists - people who make wooden art work ?
- chess contractors (or freelancers) - like for chess based movie or startup projects. example: Marketing for a chess startup, research for a movie, etc.

UPDATES based on suggestions:

- Chess composer
- Tournament director
- Staffs for chess related organization, federation, etc. -- which can actually be a career, than a mere stream of income.

Interesting observations: 
Most of the suggestions in this list can't stand out alone as a career, but would need the support of other projects to make a decent living.

**Comments are welcome. I'll update this thread based on your feedback/suggestion**

Comment: Tournament Director.

Comment: The bar for what can be a "career" seems to be very low; you couldn't make a living from most of these and would need to combine them with an actual job, or with others from the list.

Comment: +1 @RemcoGerlich I think this too too wide. For example, chess artists? Any professional artist can also do it.

Comment: There are people in that area trying to make a living ( e.g. http://www.chess-art.eu/catalog/ ) but calling that a career is going a bit far.

Comment: FIDE and national chess organisations officials?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you consider to be a "career" - if a "career" is something that occupies the majority of your time and generates your main income, then the only ones in this list that I think are plausible would be as a chess journalist/writer, or as an employee (e.g., office staff and officials) of one of the federations.  For any of the others in this list (aside from being a professional player, which only a few can do), I can't see many good ways to rely on chess as one's main source of income.

Comment: It was a very long time before I realized that tournament directors (USCF) and arbiters (FIDE) are actually paid, at least in large tournaments - I always thought they were just volunteers.  ;-)

Comment: Problem composer

Comment: @JeffY Is tournament director the same as *arbiter* ?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Good observation!

Comment: @StudentT I couldn't find another word for people who make a living making beautiful chess sets. (Wooden, metal ones)

Comment: @patbarron Thanks for your comment! It makes perfect sense. Is there another way to word the question ? hm.. 
*x Ways people make money in chess :P :) *

Comment: Problem composer! Yes, I worked on one, for a chess training site. @user58697

Comment: Is there any **professionnal** chess composer ? Even the best and most active ones don't make much money out of their composition (if any) afaik...

Comment: Missing on the list is a category that might be the most numerous: chess hustlers in parks.

Answer (score 2):

Chess software programmers is missing in the list. I can give you the following names (google them if you want to know more):

- Larry Kaufman
- Mark Lefler
- Mark Uniacke
- Robert Hyatt

Answer (score 1):

Chess photographer is popular these days, but not a full-time career.
Operator of digital boards (think Lennart Ootes)
(Selling chess books, but it's debatable)